# How wait for eth0 interface before running "ip link", "ip addr" and "ip route" commands?

Tags: linux, shell-script, networking, synology

I have the following script that I need to run on my Synology NAS at boot-up. The Synology NAS has built-in scheduled tasks with the ability to trigger tasks at boot-up.

The script I need to run is this:

```
#!/bin/sh

ip link add macvlan0 link eth0 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.0.240/32 dev macvlan0
ip link set macvlan0 up
ip route add 192.168.0.240/28 dev macvlan0
```

However, this does not work, the task seems to trigger to soon when the `eth0` interface is not yet ready to accept these commands.

Placing a `sleep 60` before all `ip *` commands, solves the issue. But it doesn't feel right to wait an arbitrary amount of seconds before doing my thing.

Given my requirements above, what's the best method to wait for the `eth0` interface to be available so that I can execute `ip *` commands?

Comment: instead of `sleep 60`, try running `ip monitor link dev eth0 | grep -q 'state UP'`.

Comment: or if that doesn't work either, `ip monitor link | grep -q 'eth0:.*UP,LOWER_UP'`.

Comment: @mosvy Both commands (without the grep) don't seem to return anything, it keeps waiting for output...

Comment: What were you expecting them to return? They should only trigger when the eth0 interface goes up.

Comment: `ip monitor link` will print info when any interface goes up, down, no-carrier, etc. It won't print anything when nothing happens at all.

Comment: How would that help me then? I mean, if I add that to the script, it would prevent the script from ever finishing... How exactly would I use `ip monitor link` to wait for the interface to be up and then proceed with the rest of the script? Would you mind posting a full answer below?

Comment: No, it will not prevent the script from ever finishing. It will finish as soon as eth0 is up. I wonder why you don't test instead of assuming: run `ip monitor link` in a terminal, and then plug the cable in and out, run ifdown & ifup from another window, etc. You can then adjust the grep, script based on your actual situation.

Comment: I'm assuming that your script will be always started before the eth0 interface is already up; if that's not the case, then you'll have to use a loop as in the other answer, or: `while ! ip link show eth0 | grep -q 'state UP'; do sleep 2; done`.

Comment: @mosvy Teted you're latest solution with the `while ! ip link show eth0` and it also worked. I think I'm going to use that one since it uses the same type of commands I need to use for the actual script. Do you want to post a full answer for that below so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: It's better that you answer with what worked for you exactly (and accept your own answer).

Comment: Doesn't seem right, the final solution came from you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the status of `eth0` from `/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate` and wait until the network interface to be up:

```
while ! [ "$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate)" = "up" ] 
do
    echo  "waiting for eth0 to be up"
    sleep 2
done

ip link add macvlan0 link eth0 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.0.240/32 dev macvlan0
ip link set macvlan0 up
ip route add 192.168.0.240/28 dev macvlan0
```

Comment: Something's wrong, the network/route is not created at boot up. It seems that the result from the `cat` is `up` when this first runs but the `ip *` commands don't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I might have fixed it... I had 2 boot up tasks on my NAS (this one and other related to something else) and I was getting some errors. I made this task be dependent on the other so that it would only run after the other one was finished. It seems to have worked but will do further testing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I eventually solved my problem with:

```bsh
while ! ip link show eth0 | grep -q 'state UP'; do
    sleep 1
done

ip link add macvlan0 link eth0 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.0.240/32 dev macvlan0
ip link set macvlan0 up
ip route add 192.168.0.240/28 dev macvlan0
```

However, I had 2 "boot-up" scheduled tasks on my Synology and I was getting some errors at boot-up. To solve that issue I configure this task to have the other one as pre-task. In other words, the tasks executed in sequence, waiting for the previous task to finish before starting the new one.